# Please help to enter text into form box with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do a tutorial and learn Selenium in python however i cant seem to get Selenium to type in the postcode using either find_element_by_class or find_element_by_XPATH.

I am using:

Python v3.9

Chrome v87

This is the URL i am practicing on(you may need to add a test item to the basket to see the button or run the script):

https://www.currys.co.uk/app/checkout

And this is my current code for the clicking:

```
# Selenium Tutorial #1

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

# Open Chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Ste1337\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

# Open webpage
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html")

# Click "Accept All Cookies" or ignore if no pop up
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
    )
    element.click()
except Exception:
    pass

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Add to Basket" or refresh page if out of stock
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "email-desktop"))
    )
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.refresh()
except:
    button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF.hZIOeU.Button-jyKNMA.GZkwS")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Continue to Basket"
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF.hZIOeU.Button-jyKNMA.sc-fzpjYC.gJohPa")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Go to checkout"
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@data-component, 'Button')][contains(@type, 'button')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

# Type in postcode
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@aria-invalid), 'False')][contains@aria-label, 'Postcode Checker')]")
search.send_keys(NG229NU)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 1):

To Identify the `input` element use either of the `locator`.

**XPATH:**

```
//input[@aria-label='Postcode Checker' and @type='search']
```

---

**CSS Selector:**

```
input[aria-label='Postcode Checker'][type='search']
```

---

To avoid synchronization issue I would suggest use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()  and enter text in the **input** box.

```
search=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@aria-label='Postcode Checker' and @type='search']")))
search.send_keys("NG229NU")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your XPath is invalid (extra bracket in first predicate and no opening bracket in second predicate). Try to replace

```
"//input[contains(@aria-invalid), 'False')][contains@aria-label, 'Postcode Checker')]"
```

with

```
"//input[contains(@aria-invalid, 'False')][contains(@aria-label, 'Postcode Checker')]"
```

Comment: strange, it seems to be exactly the same as the above line and it looks correct in sublime 3? i get an error when i post this code in on top of it :/

Comment: @StephenBrown What error did you get with suggested XPath?

Comment: line 56
    search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@aria-invalid, 'False')][contains(@aria-label, 'Postcode Checker')])
                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @StephenBrown oh, yeap. Missed closing double quotes